# get total of sub documents in a collection

Tags: mongodb

How do I get the total comments in the collection if my collection looks like this. (not the total comments per post but total for the collection.)

```
{
    _id: 1,
    post: 'content',
    comments: [
        {
            name: '',
            comment: ''
        }
    ]
}
```

If I have post A with 3 comments and post B with 5 comments. The result should be 8.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could use the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/):

```
> db.prabir.aggregate(
    { $unwind : "$comments" },
    { $group: {
        _id: '',
        count: { $sum: 1 }
    }
})
{ "result" : [ { "_id" : "", "count" : 8 } ], "ok" : 1 }
```

In a nutshell this (temporarily) creates a separate document for each comment and then increments `count` for each document.

---

For a large number of posts and comments it *might* be more efficient to keep track of the number of comments. When ever a comment is added you also increment a counter. Example:

```
// Insert a comment
> comment = { name: 'JohnDoe', comment: 'FooBar' }
> db.prabir.update(
    { post: "A" },
    {
        $push: { comments: comment },
        $inc: { numComments: 1 }
    }
)
```

Using the aggregation framework again:

```
> db.prabir.aggregate(
    { $project : { _id: 0, numComments: 1 }},
    { $group: {
        _id: '',
        count: { $sum: "$numComments" }
    }
})
{ "result" : [ { "_id" : "", "count" : 8 } ], "ok" : 1 }
```

Comment: I'm new to mongodb. That code to get a simple count... is horrific.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the `aggregate` method of the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/) for that:

```js
db.test.aggregate(
  // Only include docs with at least one comment.
  {$match: {'comments.0': {$exists: true}}},
  // Duplicate the documents, 1 per comments array entry
  {$unwind: '$comments'},
  // Group all docs together and count the number of unwound docs,
  // which will be the same as the number of comments.
  {$group: {_id: null, count: {$sum: 1}}}
);
```

**UPDATE**

As of MongoDB 2.6, there's a more efficient way to do this by using the [`$size`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/#size-aggregation) aggregation operator to directly get the number of comments in each doc:

```js
db.test.aggregate(
  {$group: {_id: null, count: {$sum: {$size: '$comments'}}}}
);
```